# Get WinRM process ID for PsExec, and Use PsExec to do keyboard input

Tags: windows, python, windows-10, winrm, psexec

As for manipulating GUI in remote desktop or/and by PsExec, I have two questions.

1. Is there any difference between Windows Remote Desktop and WinRM? I turned on respectively, and processed by `psexec -u [user name] -p [password] \\192.168.xx test.bat`. It threw an error, but `psexec` itself seemed to work. So, I think both are compatible with `psexec`.
2. I would like to ask about the prior question: [Use Powershell to start a GUI program on a remote machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/690852/use-powershell-to-start-a-gui-program-on-a-remote-machine)
   According to Victor Michnowicz, PsExec requires RDP process ID, and `tasklist` shows a session whose name includes RDP; however I couldn't find anything.
   Instead of the proposed script `PsExec.exe -s -i [RDP process ID] calc.exe`, I used `psexec -u [user name] -p [password] \\192.168.xx test.bat` as I mentioned above. But my script cannot conduct keyboard input and threw an error, so I wonder using psexec specifying RDP process ID possibly works. (Bat file executes python script)

Answer (score 0):

1. Question 1

Is there any difference between Windows Remote Desktop and WinRM?

*Yes WinRM and Windows Remote Desktop are two different protocols.*

PsExec is a tool from Sysinternals which was acquired by Microsoft, and the founder Mark Russinovich did and does very well within Microsoft. PsExec is a tool for remotely starting processes, and saying that they are compatible with remote desktop and WinRM in a bit weird because when enabled, WinRM and Remote Desktop are system services and already started by Windows itself, so stating them with PsExec is useless.

2. Question 2

Im not aware of PsExec being able to interact with Remote Desktop. PsExec is a command line program,and isn't designed to interact with any user interface workloads like Remote Desktop.

The only thing PsExec might be able to do is run a script to enable/disable rdp remotely

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. About question 2, you mean generally PsExec does not require RDP and RDP process ID, don't you? Then, does the IP address `\\192.168.xx` in my PsExec command have nothing to do with Windows RDP and WinRM?

Comment: Correct. PsExec is a light-weight telnet-replacement that lets you execute processes on other systems